# XSLT filtering template

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the input xml:

```
<PerNationalId>
    <PerNationalId>
      <nationalId>999.999.868-88</nationalId>
      <personNav>
        <PerPerson>
          <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
              <empWorkPermitNav>
                <EmpWorkPermit>
                  <documentNumber>27122165960</documentNumber>
                  <issuePlaceNav/>
                  <customString3/>
                  <documentTypeNav>
                    <PicklistOption>
                      <externalCode>6</externalCode>
                    </PicklistOption>
                  </documentTypeNav>
                </EmpWorkPermit>      
              </empWorkPermitNav>
              <jobInfoNav>
                <EmpJob>
                  <emplStatusNav>
                    <PicklistOption>
                      <externalCode>T</externalCode>
                    </PicklistOption>
                  </emplStatusNav>
                  <company>0004</company>
                </EmpJob>
              </jobInfoNav>
              <userId>60020077</userId>
            </EmpEmployment>
            <EmpEmployment>
              <empWorkPermitNav>
                <EmpWorkPermit>
                  <documentNumber>320008725351</documentNumber>
                  <issuePlaceNav/>
                  <customString3/>
                  <documentTypeNav>
                    <PicklistOption>
                      <externalCode>3</externalCode>
                    </PicklistOption>
                  </documentTypeNav>
                </EmpWorkPermit> 
              </empWorkPermitNav>
              <jobInfoNav>
                <EmpJob>
                  <emplStatusNav>
                    <PicklistOption>
                      <externalCode>A</externalCode>
                    </PicklistOption>
                  </emplStatusNav>
                  <company>0004</company>
                </EmpJob>
              </jobInfoNav>
              <userId>20028939</userId>
            </EmpEmployment>
          </employmentNav>
        </PerPerson>
      </personNav>
    </PerNationalId>
  </PerNationalId>
```

And I need the following output:

```
<PerNationalId>
    <PerNationalId>
      <nationalId>999.999.868-88</nationalId>
      <personNav>
        <PerPerson>
          <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
              <empWorkPermitNav>
                <EmpWorkPermit>
                  <documentNumber>320008725351</documentNumber>
                  <issuePlaceNav/>
                  <customString3/>
                  <documentTypeNav>
                    <PicklistOption>
                      <externalCode>3</externalCode>
                    </PicklistOption>
                  </documentTypeNav>
                </EmpWorkPermit> 
              </empWorkPermitNav>
              <jobInfoNav>
                <EmpJob>
                  <emplStatusNav>
                    <PicklistOption>
                      <externalCode>A</externalCode>
                    </PicklistOption>
                  </emplStatusNav>
                  <company>0004</company>
                </EmpJob>
              </jobInfoNav>
              <userId>20028939</userId>
            </EmpEmployment>
          </employmentNav>
        </PerPerson>
      </personNav>
    </PerNationalId>
  </PerNationalId>
```

Basically I need to remove the node EmpEmployment when sub node inside it /jobInfoNav/EmpJob/emplStatusNav/PicklistOption/externalCode has the value equal to T.

Could you please help me?

Thanks.

I have tried the following XSLT, but it's removing only the emplStatusNav tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/PerNationalId/PerNationalId/personNav/PerPerson/employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav/EmpJob/emplStatusNav/PicklistOption[(externalCode= 'T')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need something more like `xsl:template match="/EmpEmployment[PerNationalId/PerNationalId/personNav/PerPerson/employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav/EmpJob/emplStatusNav/PicklistOption[(externalCode= 'T')]]"/>`. E&OE.

Comment: I have tried but didn't work

Comment: Define "didn't work".

Comment: It's not filtering and it's not removing EmpEmployment node

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but got the same result. It's basically returning the original input xml.

Comment: Actually this is all wrong. It should be `<xsl:template match="/EmpEmployment[jobInfoNav/EmpJob/emplStatusNav/PicklistOption/@externalCode[.='T']]"/>`. You were wrong to include `PerNationalId` in the match at all, let alone twice, let alone everything else below it above `EmpEmployment`.

Comment: Not working yet. It's returning the original payload without filtering.

Comment: Well the basic idea is that you name the actual node that you want to remove, which is `/EmpEmployment`, plus a condition in `[]` to be satisfied, which in this case is the path to `@externalCode`, *which I have not checked*, plus a further condition on `externalCode` in `[]`, which in this case is `.='T'`. So check the path to `@externalCode`.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but unfortunately I'm not able to find where it's the error. Now it's 10pm here and I need to stop. Maybe tomorrow I can find a solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 3 ([fiddle online](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj3-saxonhe12-fiddle/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22EmpEmployment%5BjobInfoNav%2FEmpJob%2FemplStatusNav%2FPicklistOption%2FexternalCode%20%3D%20%27T%27%5D%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3CPerNationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CPerNationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnationalId%3E999.999.868-88%3C%2FnationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CpersonNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPerPerson%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CemploymentNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpWorkPermit%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentNumber%3E27122165960%3C%2FdocumentNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CissuePlaceNav%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcustomString3%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3E6%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpWorkPermit%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3ET%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3E0004%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CuserId%3E60020077%3C%2FuserId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpWorkPermit%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentNumber%3E320008725351%3C%2FdocumentNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CissuePlaceNav%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcustomString3%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3E3%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpWorkPermit%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3EA%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3E0004%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CuserId%3E20028939%3C%2FuserId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FemploymentNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPerPerson%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FpersonNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPerNationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2FPerNationalId%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML)):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="EmpEmployment[jobInfoNav/EmpJob/emplStatusNav/PicklistOption/externalCode = 'T']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 2 ([fiddle online](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj3-saxonhe12-fiddle/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%20%7C%20document-node%28%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22EmpEmployment%5BjobInfoNav%2FEmpJob%2FemplStatusNav%2FPicklistOption%2FexternalCode%20%3D%20%27T%27%5D%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3CPerNationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CPerNationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnationalId%3E999.999.868-88%3C%2FnationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CpersonNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPerPerson%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CemploymentNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpWorkPermit%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentNumber%3E27122165960%3C%2FdocumentNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CissuePlaceNav%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcustomString3%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3E6%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpWorkPermit%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3ET%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3E0004%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CuserId%3E60020077%3C%2FuserId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpWorkPermit%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentNumber%3E320008725351%3C%2FdocumentNumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CissuePlaceNav%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcustomString3%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3E3%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FdocumentTypeNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpWorkPermit%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FempWorkPermitNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CexternalCode%3EA%3C%2FexternalCode%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPicklistOption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FemplStatusNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccompany%3E0004%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpJob%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FjobInfoNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CuserId%3E20028939%3C%2FuserId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmpEmployment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FemploymentNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPerPerson%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FpersonNav%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPerNationalId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2FPerNationalId%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML)):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node() | document-node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="EmpEmployment[jobInfoNav/EmpJob/emplStatusNav/PicklistOption/externalCode = 'T']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```